# invalid use of Me keyword

Tags: vba, ms-access

Делаю форму с авторизацией, в аксес. Эта форма содержит поле с логином (выпадающий список) и поле с паролем (обыкновенное текстовое поле), а также кнопку Ок и Выход (текстовые надписи опущу). Данные для сверки форма берет с другой БД,таблицы Operators, в которой есть поля (ФИО, Логин, Пароль). В эту БД я таблицу импортнул (копировать ее в БД - нельзя по условиям задания). Использовать стандартные методы защиты (запароливание БД, и т.д. - тоже нельзя). Путем Гуглежа дошел к тому что нужно в обработчик кнопки Ок, повесить грубо говоря, код на VBA, который при нажатии сделает всю магию, а также запустит необходимую форму.

До сих пор с VBA дел не имел. Нашел в интернете такой вариант решения

```
Private Sub Кнопка8_Click()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Operator")
  With rst
             .FindFirst ("Логин=" & Me.Комбинированная11.Value)
             If .NoMatch Then
                   MsgBox "Данный логин отсутствует в БД"
                  Exit Sub

             Else
                 If Me.Поле6.Value <> .Fields("Пароль").Value Then
                     MsgBox "Пароль не правильный или не соответствует имени пользователя"
                      Exit Sub
                 End If
            End If

  End With
  rst.Close

  Set rst = Nothing
  End Sub
```

После этого, при запуске формы выскакивает сообщение

> invalid use of Me keyword

*"Комбинированная11"* - поле с выпадающим списком с логинами, на форме.

*"Поле6"* - поле для ввода пароля

*"Пароль"* - наименования столбца с паролями в таблице Operators

*"Кнопка8"* - кнопка на которую собственно и делается "тык", на нее я вешаю    обработчик.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50470/discussion-on-question-by-anton-invalid-use-of-me-keyword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у Вас код находится в обычном модуле, а не в модуле формы, поэтому `Me`, которое должно указывать не текущую форму, в данном контексте не существует. Вам нужно перенести код в модуль формы.

Во-вторых, т.к. Вам нужно найти в базе текст, то в запросе значение выпадающего списка нужно взять в кавычки.

И еще, в VBA параметры функции, если её результат ничему не присваивается, можно указывать без скобок (если не ошибаюсь, в ранних версиях офиса транслятор ругался на их использование без присваивания).

В итоге Вам нужно просто поменять строку

```
.FindFirst "Логин = '" & Me.Комбинированная11.Value & "'"
```